# How to test nested Router? (OLD: How to test '<select>' elements with PageLoader?)

Tags: angular-dart

I'm trying to test an application that navigates with the Router every time the user change the value of a `<select>` element. I've used `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)` on the element to catch the selected value.

I've tried to use `click()` on the `<option>` `PageLoaderElement`, but with no results.

**lib/src/line/lines_component.html:**

```html
<h2>Lines</h2>
<div *ngIf="lines?.isNotEmpty">
  Select line:
  <select [ngModel]="selectedLine" (ngModelChange)="changeLine($event)">
    <option disabled selected [ngValue]="nullLine"> -- select an option -- </option>
    <option *ngFor="let line of lines" [ngValue]="line">{{line.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div *ngIf="lines?.isEmpty">
  No lines available!
</div>
<router-outlet [routes]="Routes.all"></router-outlet>
```

**lib/src/line/lines_component.dart:**

```dart
Future<NavigationResult> changeLine(Line line) =>
      _router.navigate(_lineUrl(line.id));
```

**test/lines_po.dart:**

```dart
@ByTagName('option')
List<PageLoaderElement> get _lines;

Future<void> selectLine(var target) async {
  final lineOpt =
      _lines.firstWhere((line) => line.visibleText == target.name);
  await lineOpt.click();
}
```

**test/lines.dart:**

```dart
void selectedLineTests(InjectorProbe injector) {
  final targetLine = Line(0, 'Line 0'); // id = 0, name = 'Line 0'

  setUp(() async {
    await po.selectLine(targetLine);
    await fixture.update();
  });

  test('has navigated to detail', () async {
    final mockLocation = injector.get<MockPlatformLocation>(PlatformLocation);
    expect(
        mockLocation.pathname,
        RoutePaths.line
            .toUrl(parameters: {idParam: '${targetLine.id}'}).toString()); // '/lines/0'
  });
}
```

**Test results** (from console in browser):

```
Expected: '/lines/0'
    Actual: ''
     Which: is different. Both strings start the same, but the actual value is missing the following trailing characters: /lines/0
```

---

### **UPDATE**:

The problem seems to be related with the router, not with the `click()` on `<option>` element.
I've followed the guide on  [Webdev Dartlang site](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/testing/component/routing-components#using-a-real-router).

Changing the code to print the navigation result:

```dart
void _selectLine(int id) async {
  var res = await _router.navigate(_lineUrl(id));
  print(res);
}
```

During the test it prints: `NavigationResult.INVALID_ROUTE`.

I don't know if it helps, but this is how my routes are organized:

**lib/src/route_paths.dart:**

```dart
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

const idParam = 'id';

class RoutePaths {
  static final lines = RoutePath(path: 'lines');
}
```

**lib/src/routes.dart:**

```dart
import 'not_found_component.template.dart' as not_found_template;
import 'line/lines_component.template.dart' as lines_template;

import 'route_paths.dart';
export 'route_paths.dart';

class Routes {
  static final lines = RouteDefinition(
    routePath: RoutePaths.lines,
    component: lines_template.LinesComponentNgFactory,
  );

  static final all = <RouteDefinition>[
    lines,
    RouteDefinition.redirect(
      path: '',
      redirectTo: RoutePaths.lines.toUrl(),
    ),
    RouteDefinition(
      path: '.+',
      component: not_found_template.NotFoundComponentNgFactory,
    ),
  ];
}
```

**lib/src/line/route_paths.dart:**

```dart
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

import '../route_paths.dart' as _parent;
export '../route_paths.dart' show idParam;

class RoutePaths {
  static final line = RoutePath(
    path: ':${_parent.idParam}',
    parent: _parent.RoutePaths.lines,
  );
}
```

**lib/src/line/routes.dart:**

```dart
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

import 'line_component.template.dart' as line_template;

import 'route_paths.dart';
export 'route_paths.dart';

class Routes {
  static final line = RouteDefinition(
    routePath: RoutePaths.line,
    component: line_template.LineComponentNgFactory,
  );

  static final all = <RouteDefinition>[
    line,
  ];
}
```

Comment: Please, please take some time to familiarize yourself with the site before using it! This is _not_ a forum. You do _not_ add "solved" and similar tags to your title. You do _not_ edit your _question_ to insert your _answer_. Read [ask]. Read the [faq].

Comment: Ok, I will move the solution found in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to import the parent `Routes` class to make the test works:

**test/dart**:

```dart
import 'package:frontend/src/line/routes.dart';
import 'package:frontend/src/routes.dart' as parent_routes;

[...]

@Component(
  selector: 'test',
  template: '''
    <my-lines></my-lines>
    <router-outlet [routes]="[parent_routes.Routes.lines]"></router-outlet>
  ''',
  directives: [RouterOutlet, LinesComponent],
  exports: [parent_routes.Routes],
)
class TestComponent {
  final Router router;

  TestComponent(this.router);
}
```

I don't know if this is the correct way to do this. Comments are welcome!!!